# how do i import css inside react component?

Tags: css, reactjs

i am creating a react component `Comp1` and i am importing a css file inside it like this->

```
import "./style.css";
```

inside `style.css` i am doing something like this->

```
@import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

but the problem is, this is applying css to all components in react and ruining everything. i want to apply only inside the particular component `Comp1` and specifically in this tag->

```
<div className="comp1">
</div>
```

please guide me on this. how do i do that? let me know if u need any more info.

Comment: That's because the Bootstrap CSS, once included, runs its rules on everything. It's not tied to a specific component.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Create React App, you can use [CSS modules](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/) for this.

Answer (score 1):

like [@tymzap](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11268398/tymzap) mentioned, you can use css modules.

In JS, you need to rename your filename.css to filename.module.css
and you need to import that css file to your react component

```
import styles from "../related_directory/filename.module.css
....
<Component className={styles.some_classname_in_your_css} />
```

In TS, you need to create a type declaration file named declarations.d.ts
in that file you need to define css or scss files as modules.

```
declare module "*.module.scss"
```

hope it will help.